# How to make Terminal windows persistent

Tags: macos, terminal

How can I make it so Terminal will remember the currently open windows on Quit, and reopen those windows, with all the existing text intact?

I have two machines:

- Both on El Cap
- Both with identical Terminal preferences, including:

  - Profiles > Window > Restore text when reopening windows **[checked]**
  - Profiles > Shell > When the shell exits **[Don't close the window]**
- Both with identical .bash_profiles (just for LSCOLORS)

On the first machine, Terminal reopens windows exactly as I left them before Quit.

On the second machine, Terminal always starts with an empty bash window.  I can still press up to get previous commands.  (And the scrollbar is different on the second machine, FWIW).

I can't figure out what's responsible for the (desired) behavior on the first machine, so I haven't been able to port it to the second machine.  Any suggestions?

Comment: For me, my terminal windows restored for years, until recently. I think that the upgrade to Mojave or one of the security fixes introduced the problem by changing the settings the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have "Close windows when quitting an app" checked on the machine that does not restore the terminal windows (your second machine).

This setting is in **System Preferences -> General**  *not* in your Terminal preferences.

Uncheck this box to get the desired behavior.  Understand however that this behavior can extend to other applications as well - it is not restricted to Terminal.app

As for the scroll bars, I suspect you will find that the **Show Scroll Bars** radio button in **System Preferences -> General** is not set the same on your two machines.

Comment: Is there a way to enable this behavior only for Terminal app?